# Do man pages for the same command differ depending on source?

Tags: manpage

Apologies for the poorly worded question but when I look at the `-i` switch in `man sed`, I see:

> ```
>    -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
>           edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
> ```

That's all.

But then I came across [Quick note about sed’s edit in place option](http://joemaller.com/823/quick-note-about-seds-edit-in-place-option/) with a much longer explanation for `sed -i` **also** from a man page:

```
From the sed manpage:

-i extension
   Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.
   If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It
   is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place
   editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situ-
   ations where disk space is exhausted, etc.
```

So where can one access more detailed man pages? And does anyone know the source of the more elaborate version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have found may be the [man page of the sed utility on a Mac OS X system](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) which is different from the sed utility you are using on Ubuntu. As far as I know while the sed utility on Mac OS X originates in BSD Unix, the sed utility on Ubuntu has been written by the GNU project.

If you need more detailed documentation about a `GNU utility` then it's worth opening its `info` document instead of its man page. [In the GNU project, man pages are secondary.](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Man-Pages) For example take a look at what you can find about the `-i` option in sed's `info` page:

> ```
> `-i[SUFFIX]'
> `--in-place[=SUFFIX]'
>
>    This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.  GNU
>    `sed' does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to
>    this file rather than to the standard output.(1).
>
>    This option implies `-s'.
>
>    When the end of the file is reached, the temporary file is renamed
>    to the output file's original name.  The extension, if supplied,
>    is used to modify the name of the old file before renaming the
>    temporary file, thereby making a backup copy(2)).
>
>    This rule is followed: if the extension doesn't contain a `*',
>    then it is appended to the end of the current filename as a
>    suffix; if the extension does contain one or more `*' characters,
>    then _each_ asterisk is replaced with the current filename.  This
>    allows you to add a prefix to the backup file, instead of (or in
>    addition to) a suffix, or even to place backup copies of the
>    original files into another directory (provided the directory
>    already exists).
>
>    If no extension is supplied, the original file is overwritten
>    without making a backup.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what source you use to install the program, there will be different versions, and sometimes on newer versions the maintainers update the manual for the application. I suppose the most accurate one is always the one you have installed, since is the manual for the exact same version in your system. If you search for help online, the parameters may be outdated (or too new). But sometimes online manuals are better because you may find more extensive explanations, and even examples of how to use the parameters, flags, etc.